# Не понимаю как запустить компилятор Roslyn в Докере Linux

Tags: c#, linux, docker, roslyn

Без докера все работало, писал вот так.

```
private static string CompileCs(string filePath)
        {
            var pc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    Arguments = $@"""C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Console.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Runtime.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"" ""{filePath}.cs"" -out:""{filePath}.dll""",
                    FileName = "dotnet",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                }
            };
            pc.Start();
            pc.WaitForExit();
            var err = pc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            return err;
        }
```

С докером, поменял код на

```
        private static string CompileCs(string filePath)
        {
            var pc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    Arguments = @"usr/bin/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll",
                    FileName = "dotnet",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                }
            };
            pc.Start();
            string err = pc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            pc.WaitForExit();
            return err;
        }
```

Но получаю ошибку:

**Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.\r\nPossible reasons for this include:\r\n  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.\r\n  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-usr/bin/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll does not exist.\r\n  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.\n**

Сам DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp.net:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SolutionsTester/SolutionsTester.Web.csproj", "SolutionsTester/"]
COPY ["SolutionsTester.DataAccess/SolutionsTester.DataAccess.csproj", "SolutionsTester.DataAccess/"]
COPY ["SolutionTester.Domain/SolutionTester.Domain.csproj", "SolutionTester.Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SolutionsTester/SolutionsTester.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SolutionsTester"
RUN dotnet build "SolutionsTester.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SolutionsTester.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SolutionsTester.Web.dll"]
```

Comment: `@"/usr/bin/...`

Comment: @aepot Немного другая ошибка:
**"realpath(/usr/bin/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll) failed: Not a directory\nCould not execute because the specified command or file was not found.\r\nPossible reasons for this include:\r\n  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.\r\n  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-/usr/bin/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll does not exist.\r\n  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.\n",**

Comment: Ну, значит у вас нет такого файла по указанному пути.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный путь: **/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll -r: /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.5/System.Private.CoreLib.dll - r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.5/System.Console.dll - r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.5/System.Runtime.dll - r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.5/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll {filePath}.cs -out:{filePath}.dll**